# How do we prove that $f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = x_{n}$ and $f(0) = x$ is continuous.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise**

Consider the metric space $C = \left\{\frac{1}{n+1} : n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\{0\}$ with the usual metric induced by the metric of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Prove the sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ is convergent to some point $x\in X$ iff the function $f:C\to X$ defined by $f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = x_{n}$ and $f(0) = x$ is continuous.

**My attempt**

If $f$ is continuous, then it maps convergent sequences into convergent sequences.

Since $\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we conclude that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = f(0) = x
\end{align*}

On the other hand, if $x_{n}\to x$, we have to prove that $f$ is continuous.

This is where I get stuck.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: do you mean continuous at 0?

Comment: @Ilovemath The exercise left it unspecified.

Comment: As the answer explains, since the domain only has one limit point, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that metric, every point of $C$ other than $0$ is an isolated point, and therefore every function from $C$ into a metric space $(X,d)$ is continuous at every point other than $0$.

You proved correctly that, if $f$ is continuous, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Now, suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$. And there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\frac1{n+1}<\delta\implies n\geqslant N$. Therefore$$\left|\frac1{n+1}-0\right|<\delta\implies|x-x_n|<\varepsilon\iff\left|x-f\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)\right|<\varepsilon,$$and so $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I was reading this solution and I don't understand one step. The fact that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}< \delta \implies n \ge N$ comes from the fact that for any $\delta>0$ and for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $\frac{1}{n+1}<\delta$ as solutions  when $n \ge \frac{1-\delta}{\delta}$ and so when $n$ is bigger than the maximum among the index $N$ of the limit definition of $x_n$ and $\frac{1-\delta}{\delta}$ (and you've called again $N$ this maximum) the chain of implications you've written holds? Or it yours a different reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: @Gwyn That was my approach.